# Strange memory behaviour - C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a very strange issue in a seemingly simple code (For debugging purposes, I simplified it now to pretty much this code):

```
class Buf {
   Frame ** frames;

   Buf(int a);
   int a;
   long b, c, d

}
Buf::Buf(int size){

   a = size;
   frames = new Frame*[size]; 

   for (int f = 0; f < size; ++f){
       frames[f] = new Frame;
   }

   b = c = d = 5; // (***)
}
```

Frame class is very simple and small, I disabled any memory operations in its constructor/destructor.

In `main` I am calling:

```
Buf* buf =  new Buf(50);
```

Once in a while it works fine, but most of the time it works ok until the (***) line, then when I pass this line as I can see in the debugger, the *frame, frame[1], etc. become equals to 5 (!) or whatever other number I put in the assignment.

If I try to run it from the command line, it tells me about bad memory access.

As I said, I simplified my program to be extremely trivial, still cannot find an error.

Any suggestions/help would be fantastic!

UPDATE:

I copied the code to another computer (with similar configuration) and I cannot reproduce the problem there. On the original computer, I can reproduce the problem, whether I run the project from XCode or Eclipse/command line (different copies of the code).

Comment: Why are you managing pointers yourself? That's error prone.

Comment: Three things: Why do you use a pointer to pointer to `Frame` instead of `std::vector<Frame>`? Then why don't you use initializer lists? And why do you dynamically allocate the `Buf` object in your `main` function?

Comment: Suggestion: if you believe that the `Frame` class is unrelated to the problem, replace it with `int`, add `main`, and you've got an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will significantly help in diagnostics.

Comment: That's too much simplification, we cannot reproduce the error from that code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Symptoms look like you mishandled pointers _somewhere_ in your program. Note that if that happened, it's undefined behavior and _anything_ can happen afterwards, including random changes of random variables in random lines in debugger.

Comment: All, a. fixed the ; b. agree vector is safer, but it should not prevent my code to work. c. Will try d. I am getting there - for now I am just asking for any suggestions - I was not able to find so far the minimal reproducible code

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude some people want to actually understand an issue and not scrap the whole thing in favor of a library just because they can't figure it out.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there's nothing wrong with managing pointers. It isn't as if it's so complicated that it's impossible.

Comment: @Erix It's error prone though. At the end you may reinvent the wheel and write your own classes for [dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), to overcome all these problems introduced with using `new` and `delete` directly?

Comment: @Erix `std::vector` is not just part of any old library, it's part of the *standard* library. All C++ compilers comes with it. It contains a lot of thing that will make every C++ programmers life easier, and makes the code easier to read, understand and maintain. If I was a teacher and this is part of a school assignment, and it's *not* about pointers, then I would give the person giving me this code a very low grade.

Comment: I think we are missing information needed to answer the problem. The `Frame` class might be small and have no memory operations, but might actually be part of the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm glad you weren't my teacher. I learned memory management much more intimately by avoiding libraries. Sure STL is great, but to answer a programming question about memory by suggesting to simply avoid it is not helpful.

Comment: @Erix ***If*** it was an exercise in manual memory management then yes using pointers would be mandatory. But if not, then *don't do it*. As we don't know if this is such a manual memory management exercise, the best advice is going to be to not use pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "you're an idiot, don't do X" (paraphrased) is not usually the best way to convince someone of the wrongness of their ways. Instead, try "your attempt at X fails because of these reasons. As an aside, getting X right is complicated; you might prefer method Y or method Z instead".

Comment: @WouterVerhelst But we *can't* say "this fails because...", because there's simply not enough information. We can *guess* that there is a problem with memory, and such problems are generally solved by removing the use of pointers. But that's all we can really say for now.

Comment: I understand, I am just asking for suggestions on what to look at further - I don't expect the solution.

Comment: At the moment, I recompiled the code on another computer (with identical OS/compiler, etc.) and I am not getting this error so far - continue to try

Comment: @Alex A debugger, and something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) are the best tools to help you find memory issues, if you don't want to change your code to not use pointers.

Comment: I am using XCode, their debugger is pretty good. Also, tried Eclipse/GDB, but having a bit of an issue making it work (another topic :))

Comment: I hear Valgrind works in OS X these days. That should be the first tool to use. More often than not it will tell you what your problem is right away.

Comment: @Alex yeah, but XCode's dependency tracker is pretty shit. I've noticed that sometimes it does things like that, and then all you need to do is "project->clean", "project->build", and it magically disappears. Did you try that?

Comment: If you have a [MCVE], please post it. If you can't produce one, and you expect suggestions on how to debug the problem, please mention it is the question so that people stop close-voting it.

Comment: Yes, I tried to clean/rebuild, also had the same issue from Eclipse as well as from the command line. I now rebuild the project on another computer and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: n.m. - I asked for suggestions - please see my original post. Thanks

Comment: You probably should say something along these lines. "I don't have a minimal example that reproduces the problem. I'm not looking for an answer that would point out a bug in this specific program. I want to know how I can debug this kind of problem myself". Makes your question absolutely clear. (Again, the answer to this is "use valgrind").

Answer (score 0):

```
frames = new Frames*[size];
```

that's wrong, the "frames" variable is defined as pointer to pointer to `Frame`, not pointer to pointer to `Frames`.

Comment: True, but very unclear if that is the actual problem. Most likely not because that would be a compilation error. We should wait for that MCVE.

Comment: @BaummitAugen it is very unclear indeed, but based on the minimal amount of code given, seems like an obvious candidate. It would be a compilation error if Frames *did not exist*; but since we're using pointers here and not vectors or safe pointers some such, and depending on the used compiler and its settings, this may "only" be a warning but compile just fine. However, If sizeof(Frames) < sizeof(Frame), this will go horribly horribly wrong.

Comment: *"but based on the minimal amount of code given, seems like an obvious candidate."* And that's why I suggest we wait until the question is in an answerable state.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's `Frame**` in the declaration vs `Frames*` in the `new[]` expression. Note the extra 's'. Misread that too at first.

Comment: My apologies, corrected it in the question: it is of course new Frame*[size]

Comment: If this was the problem it would have been a build error, not a run-time problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there are plenty of creative ways in which this would compile correctly but still result in a run-time problem. All depends on things like compiler in use, its version, the settings being used, and whether Frames exists or what it does. Pointers have "interesting" properties :-)

Comment: Also, *"If sizeof(Frames) < sizeof(Frame), this will go horribly horribly wrong."*: Not really, we would need `sizeof(Frame*) != sizeof(Frames*)` for that to be an issue, and that's uncommon at least.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst True, and it could easily be that there *was* a `Frames` class or structure in the code, but that the OP just didn't show us.